# Counting the number of characters in input with getchar() method

Tags: c, getchar

I am studying C from *The C Programming Language*. I have tried to make the following code work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int char_count = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++char_count;
    printf("Number of chars are %ld ", char_count);
    return 0;
}
```

I build and run the code. Then, I enter a random word and press enter. I expect to see a number in the next line, but what happens is that cursor moves to the next line. When I enter a new word same thing happens. What am I missing?

Edit: I expect `getchar()` to return `EOF` when the program finishes getting the characters of the first word.

Comment: when are you expecting getchar to return EOF?

Comment: Carriage return/newline is not `EOF`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are pressing `enter`/`return` you are generating `\n` or `\r\n` based on the whether you are using unix/osx or windows. You are not generation EOF character.

To generate `EOF` character you need to press `^D` on unix/osx or `^Z` on windows.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it seems that you accepted other answer

Answer (score 0):

Inputting the EOF character into the command prompt is always tricky. Doing what @Sarvex recommended will do the trick, by using Ctrl+Z on Windows or Ctrl+D on Unix.

One other interesting thing that you can do without making any changes to your code is instead of having your program accept input from the command prompt, you can redirect input to your program from a text file.

If you had a text file named, "data.txt" with the following text in it:

> Hello World. How are you doing?

And the name of your program, after compiling the code was `charCount`. You could do the following:

[image]

The output I received was, `Number of chars are 31`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did not know how to read from a text file with command prompt.

Answer (score -2):

If you change the `EOF` to `\n` character, it will do the work after pressing the enter key:

```
int c = 0;
while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF))
    ++char_count;
```

P.S: Improved Using @David Bowling suggestion.

Comment: The change should be to add a test for `'\n'` instead of just replacing `EOF` with `'\n'`: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}`. Note that `getchar()` returns `EOF` if there is an error; you want to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: This new code also will not count the number of characters in a file.

Comment: @David Bowling, Thanks, I improved the code using your suggestion.

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the original question. 

I expect getchar() to return EOF when the program finishes getting the characters of the first word.

Comment: @apeirogon, If you read the original question more carefully, you may see this: "I expect to see a number in the next line, but what happens is that cursor moves to the next line." This means the `getchar()` is terminated after hitting the enter which is the `\n` character and not `EOF`, because we're reading from terminal and not a file.

Comment: @hmofrad if you read the question agian you will see "I expect getchar() to return EOF when the program finishes getting the characters of the first word." I am not sure why even we are discussing that ?